# adding custom code as a wordpress plugin

Tags: plugins, plugin-development

i have written a small piece of code so when a user forgets and resets the password it will be emailed to the user

currently i have added that code directly to the wp-login.php page

```
do_action( 'validate_password_reset', $errors, $user );

if ( ( ! $errors->get_error_code() ) && isset( $_POST['pass1'] ) && !empty( $_POST['pass1'] ) ) {
            reset_password($user, $_POST['pass1']);
    setcookie( $rp_cookie, ' ', time() - YEAR_IN_SECONDS, $rp_path, COOKIE_DOMAIN, is_ssl(), true );
    //////////////////////////// 


///my code


/////////////////////////////
login_header( __( 'Password Reset' ), '<p class="message reset-pass">' . __( 'Your password has been reset.' ) . ' <a href="' . esc_url( wp_login_url() ) . '">' . __( 'Log in' ) . '</a></p>' );
login_footer();
exit;
```

the problem im having is modifying the core is not a good idea.. so instead of modifying the core i need to add it as a plugin..

i went through the https://codex.wordpress.org/Writing_a_Plugin page but im still not clear about it coz im new to wordpress plugins thing.

Can someone please guide me on how this can be done?

Comment: Did you find a solution on this?

Comment: @jdm2112 nt yet.. im trying to work on a solution based on your answer... im new to this wordpress plugin thing.. trying to grasp it :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to hook into that action, not repeat it.  I believe you want something like this.   The function will fire with the `validate_password_reset`

```
add_action( 'validate_password_reset', 'my_passwd_function', 10, 2 );

function my_passwd_function() {

    echo 'Your Code Here';
    return;

}
```